# no remote repository specified from new rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I am trying to add new rails apps to an existing example repository. I've done this before. I'm using a current Debian on Google Cloud Platform Compute Engine Instance, using Rails 5.1.4 and git 2.11.0.

In short, I can add a new rails app, but if I try to add/commit/push *from inside that application's directories*, I get errors. If I add/commit/push from above the top level directory for the application, everything works.

Recreating this is simple. I use:

```
rails new foo
```

to create a new rails app. I then add the app, commit, and push:

```
git add .
git commit -m "testing"
git push
```

Which results in the following output (abbreviated):

> [master 95cb836] testing
>
> 76 files changed, 1197 insertions(+)
>
> create mode 100644 railapps/foo/.gitignore
>
> create mode 100644 railapps/foo/Gemfile
>
> ...

At this point I have no problems. However, when I go into that app and try to do a pull or push, I get the following errors:

```
git pull
```

> fatal: No remote repository specified.  Please, specify either a URL or a
>
> remote name from which new revisions should be fetched.

```
git push
```

> Either specify the URL from the command-line or configure a remote repository 
>   using
>
> git remote add
>
> and then push using the remote name
>
> ```
> git push <name>
> ```

OK, simple enough, just specify the remote, right?

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:pathto/myrepo.git

git push --set-upstream origin master
```

Which results in:

> error: src refspec master does not match any.
>
> error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:pathto/myrepo.git'

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the `--set-upstream` option in this case.
Just use :

```
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not sure when this was added, but by default rails (at least as of version 5.1.4) now initializes a new project as an empty git repo (using git init). A call to

```
rails new --help
```

shows

> -G, [--skip-git], [--no-skip-git]                      # Skip .gitignore file

but this is misleading; it actually does not call git init at all with this option, thus solving the problem. So if I call

```
rails new whatever -G
```

the problem doesn't happen.